# how to reduce white space(right width) in my box

Tags: html, css

Hello I have two contents in my table, so two boxes that contain contents in html. I want to reduce the distance between these two boxes, but I realized size of one box is too big that they are just white space. I'm having trouble reducing that size. can someone please help me with this?
so, cell x and cell y that's in same row to be located closer.

```
<table class="table">
        <tr id="cell">
---------------------------------------------------------------(one cell)
          <td class="vert-align">
  <div class="voting-space">

            <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <br />

<span class="col-md-12" style="height:1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; bottom:10px; padding-left:0.01em;
"><h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4></span>     <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
          </td>

--------------------------------------------------------------------(the other cell)
<td class="vert-align">
  {% if post.url %}
      <h4 id="line">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 15px; text-decoration:none;"> <img src="{{post.image}}" height="85" width="85"/><span id="title-font">{{ post.title }}</span></a>
        <span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span>
        <span class="discuss" style="color:red;"><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">토론장 입장</a></span>
        <br />
        <span class="post-info">{{ post.pub_date | timesince }}전/<a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' post.moderator.username %}">{{ post.moderator.username }}</a>작성/<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>{{post.views}}/<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{{post.category}}</a></span>
      </h4>
  {% else %}
<h4><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" style="margin-left: 15px;">{{ post.title }}</a><span style="margin-left: 15px; "class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span></h4>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controlling "cellpadding" in CSS, you can simply use padding on table cells. E.g. for 10px of "cellpadding":

```
td { 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

For "cellspacing", you can apply the border-spacing CSS property to your table. E.g. for 10px of "cellspacing":

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

This property will even allow separate horizontal and vertical spacing, something you couldn't do with old-school "cellspacing".